# What does this stream of characters represent (when using unbuffer)?

Tags: terminal, tty

I'm using `unbuffer` to run a command that expects to be run within a tty. However it's returning the following:

`[?1049h[?1049l[?12l[?25h(B[?12l[?25happ: empty picture`

What do these characters represent?

I can see a similar string of chars here:
https://github.com/nsf/tbclock/blob/7535693d14ab0cc37a2115d88d558babebde2e36/termbox/term.c#L19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the *printable* part of escape sequences for

- switching to the alternate screen `[?1049h`
- switching back to the normal screen `[?1049l`
- making the cursor blink
- setting the character-set to ASCII

See [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) for a list...  the *escape* character happens to be non-printing, and perhaps lost by `unbuffer`.